# adapting Python code into PHP with a reference issue

Tags: php, python

I'm trying to convert some python code into PHP and I have some difficulties to get the same output.
Actually, I think the problem is about working with a dictionary by reference in Python, more difficult in PHP

Here is my Python code :

```
import json
from pprint import pprint
a=["/",
"/page1.html",
"/cocktails/receipe/page1.html",
"/cocktails/receipe/page2.html",
"/cocktails/page3.html",
"/article/magazine",
"/article/mood/page1.html"]

def create(path,dictionaryandarray):
    #print(path[0],dictionary)
    if not path:
        return
    for ele in dictionaryandarray:
        if 'name' in ele and ele['name'] == path[0]:
            ele.setdefault('children',[])
            if (path[1:]):
                create(path[1:],ele['children'])
            return
    newvalue={'name':path[0]}
    if (path[1:]):
        newvalue['children']=[]

    dictionaryandarray.append(newvalue)
    if (path[1:]):
        create(path[1:], dictionaryandarray[-1]['children'])
d = []
for i in a:
    parts = [j for j in i.split('/') if j != '']
    create(parts ,d)

data={'name':'/','children':d}
data=json.dumps(data, indent=4, sort_keys=False)
# pprint(data)
print(data)
```

and here is my PHP code :

```
    <?php
$rows=[
"page1.html",
"/cocktails/receipe/page1.html",
"/cocktails/receipe/page2.html",
"/cocktails/page3.html",
"/article/magazine",
"/article/mood/page1.html"];

$res = [];
$i=0;
foreach($rows as $row){

    $suffix = preg_replace("#https?://[^/]*#", "", $row);

    $parts = array_values(array_filter(preg_split("#[/\?]#", $suffix)));
    create($parts, $res);    
}

$data=['name' => '/','children' =>$res];

$data= json_encode($data, true);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $data;

function create($path, &$res){

    if (empty($path))
        return;


    if (is_null($res))
        return;

    foreach ($res as $key => $ele){

        if (array_key_exists("name", $ele) && $ele['name'] == $path[0]){
            if (!array_key_exists("children", $ele)){
                $res[$key]['children'] = [];
            }

            if (count($path) > 1){
                create(array_slice($path, 1), $res[$key]['children']);
            }
            return;
        }
    }

    $newvalue = ["name" => $path[0]];
    if (count($path)>1){
        $newvalue['children'] = [];
    }
    $res[] = $newvalue;
    if (count($path)> 1){
        create(array_slice($path, 1), end($res)['children']);
    }
}
```

what I'm getting is that the `$res` variable is not populated as python do. I tryed to pass it by reference but get the same problem.

May be there is a way to populate it the same way than Python do, but I don't know how to do.

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

PHP's foreach is implemented as call-by-value instead of call-by-reference. So your `$ele['children']` assignments are doing nothing. Also, mix doing return with pass-by-reference doesn't help.

You may convert your `create()` to full call-by-reference style like this:

```php
<?php

function create($path, &$res){

    if (empty($path))
        return;


    if (is_null($res))
        return;

    foreach ($res as $key => $ele){

        if (array_key_exists("name", $ele) && $ele['name'] == $path[0]){
            if (!array_key_exists("children", $ele)){
                $res[$key]['children'] = [];
            }

            if (count($path) > 1){
                create(array_slice($path, 1), $res[$key]['children']);
            }
            return;
        }
    }

    $newvalue = ["name" => $path[0]];
    if (count($path)>1){
        $newvalue['children'] = [];
    }
    $res[] = $newvalue;
    if (count($path)> 1){
        create(array_slice($path, 1), end($res)['children']);
    }
}
```

Then you should simply rewrite `$res = create($parts, $res);` to `create($parts, $res);`. Things should work.

Comment: thanks @koalayeung I updated my code (here) with your advices but still dont get the same results than the python version. for some reasons, I can't get the children populated